# What does the semicolon represent in an awk action?

Tags: linux, awk

I'm attempting to decipher the action in the following `awk` statement specifically what the `;` after the first user defined variable refers to.

```
{ num_gold++; wt_gold += $2 }
```

Comment: It seems to be a delimiter between `num_gold++` and `wt_gold += $2`. I don't think it refers to anything.

Comment: A semicolon `traditionally` just separates statements. This is used here so the code can be put on a single line.

Comment: @nhahtdh - What purpose does it serve?

Comment: @ChristopheD - What do you mean by placing code in a single line? Why would I not be able to do `{num_gold++ wt_gold +=2}`?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: then I guess awk would not understand what you are trying to feed it (the language needs to know when a statements ends somehow - most of the time by newline or semicolon).

Comment: @ChristopheD - Okay so if I wanted to print the results of each variable would I then need to do as follows `{print num_gold++; print wt_gold+=2}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `awk`, you can write two statements in one line separated by `;`(semi-colon)

```
{ num_gold++; wt_gold += $2 }
```

Otherwize, you should put them into separated lines:

```
{
    num_gold++
    wt_gold += $2
}
```

---

To print the variables, you just add `print` before the variables:

```
{
    num_gold++
    wt_gold += $2

    print num_gold
    print wt_gold
}
```

As I said, you can put them all in one line:

```
{ num_gold++; wt_gold += $2; print num_gold; print wt_gold; }
```

It's too long!

`print` also accepts multiple arguments, so try `print num_gold, wt_gold`.

Comment: Thanks. So does that mean I am limited to just 2 statements in each line as well as that if I wanted them in a single line, I am required to use the `;` delimiter.

Comment: Any number of statements. just add `;` at the end.

Comment: Thanks. So is `;` the only delimiter I can use?

Comment: Most syntaxes in `awk` is the same as `C`.

Comment: When you have a large number of follow-up questions, it's a sign that you should actually consider reading the manual, you know.